# Sage: Torsion parameter in elliptic_curves db

Tags: database, sage, elliptic-curve

Looking at the [Tables of elliptic curves of a given rank](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ec_database.html) documentation page and at Mazur's Theorem, a question pops out at me: How do I specify the difference between, for example, $\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z} 2 \times \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z} 2$ from $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z} 4$ if the torsion parameter is an integer when querying the tables? Is there a way to query for elliptic curves that have torsion which is a particular product of nontrivial cyclic groups?

[image: Mazur's Theorem from Andrew Snowden's Umich course]

Really, the icing on the cake would be an interface to the LMFDB with filtering capabilities on all of the fields available on their website. Does anything satisfying my desires exist?